# datatables serverside html entity in post data

Tags: php, post, datatables

I'm writing a server side application for the jquery plugin DataTables, since it's not working I simplified my implementation.
This is the js part:

```
$('#foo').DataTable({
 "processing": true,
 "serverSide": true,
 "ajax": {
    "url": uri_api,
    "method": "POST",
    "data": function(d) {
       d.arguments="get_foo"
    }
 },
"columns": [
  { "data": "ONE" },
  { "data": "TWO" },
  { "data": "THREE" }
 ]
});
```

And this is my api.php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
set_error_handler("error_handler", E_ALL);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {http_response_code(200);exit();}
var_dump($data);
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
var_dump(json_last_error_msg());
die();
```

As you can see it's a very basic try, this is my real anser of api.php:

```
NULL
string(12259) "draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=ID&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=Hostname&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=IP&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=IP_List&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=Service&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=Management_Platform&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=Service_Owner&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=Service_Area&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=Service_SOM&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=Service_Reference&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B10%5D%5Bdata%5D=Classes&columns%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B11%5D%5Bdata%5D=Instance&columns%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B12%5D%5Bdata%5D=Instance_Address&columns%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B13%5D%5Bdata%5D=TAG&columns%5B13%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B13%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B14%5D%5Bdata%5D=Env&columns%5B14%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B14%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B14%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B14%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B14%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B15%5D%5Bdata%5D=Status&columns%5B15%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B15%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B15%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B15%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B15%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B16%5D%5Bdata%5D=Domain&columns%5B16%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B16%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B16%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B16%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B16%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B17%5D%5Bdata%5D=DC&columns%5B17%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B17%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B17%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B17%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B17%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B18%5D%5Bdata%5D=Role&columns%5B18%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B18%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B18%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B18%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B18%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B19%5D%5Bdata%5D=Service_Platform&columns%5B19%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B19%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B19%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B19%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B19%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B20%5D%5Bdata%5D=OS&columns%5B20%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B20%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B20%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B20%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B20%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B21%5D%5Bdata%5D=SW&columns%5B21%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B21%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B21%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B21%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B21%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B22%5D%5Bdata%5D=Baseline&columns%5B22%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B22%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B22%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B22%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B22%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B23%5D%5Bdata%5D=Cluster&columns%5B23%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B23%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B23%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B23%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B23%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B24%5D%5Bdata%5D=Last_Communication&columns%5B24%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B24%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B24%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B24%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B24%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B25%5D%5Bdata%5D=Compliance&columns%5B25%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B25%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B25%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B25%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B25%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B26%5D%5Bdata%5D=ACS&columns%5B26%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B26%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B26%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B26%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B26%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B27%5D%5Bdata%5D=LMS&columns%5B27%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B27%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B27%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B27%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B27%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B28%5D%5Bdata%5D=EPO&columns%5B28%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B28%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B28%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B28%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B28%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B29%5D%5Bdata%5D=ACS_DB&columns%5B29%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B29%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B29%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B29%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B29%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B30%5D%5Bdata%5D=ACS_MW&columns%5B30%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B30%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B30%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B30%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B30%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B31%5D%5Bdata%5D=LMS_DB&columns%5B31%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B31%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B31%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B31%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B31%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B32%5D%5Bdata%5D=LMS_MW&columns%5B32%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B32%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B32%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B32%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B32%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B33%5D%5Bdata%5D=LMS_L285&columns%5B33%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B33%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B33%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B33%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B33%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B34%5D%5Bdata%5D=RMT_Update&columns%5B34%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B34%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B34%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B34%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B34%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B35%5D%5Bdata%5D=ACS_OS_Update&columns%5B35%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B35%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B35%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B35%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B35%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B36%5D%5Bdata%5D=LMS_OS_Update&columns%5B36%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B36%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B36%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B36%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B36%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B37%5D%5Bdata%5D=EPO_Update&columns%5B37%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B37%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B37%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B37%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B37%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B38%5D%5Bdata%5D=ACS_DB_Update&columns%5B38%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B38%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B38%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B38%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B38%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B39%5D%5Bdata%5D=ACS_MW_Update&columns%5B39%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B39%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B39%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B39%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B39%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B40%5D%5Bdata%5D=LMS_DB_Update&columns%5B40%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B40%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B40%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B40%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B40%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B41%5D%5Bdata%5D=LMS_MW_Update&columns%5B41%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B41%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B41%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B41%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B41%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B42%5D%5Bdata%5D=LMS_L285_Update&columns%5B42%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B42%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B42%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B42%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B42%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B43%5D%5Bdata%5D=Host_Source&columns%5B43%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B43%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B43%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B43%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B43%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B44%5D%5Bdata%5D=Instance_Source&columns%5B44%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B44%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B44%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B44%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B44%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B45%5D%5Bdata%5D=IP_Source&columns%5B45%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B45%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B45%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B45%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B45%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B46%5D%5Bdata%5D=Service_Source&columns%5B46%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B46%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B46%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B46%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B46%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B47%5D%5Bdata%5D=Host_ID&columns%5B47%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B47%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B47%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B47%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B47%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B48%5D%5Bdata%5D=Instance_Host_ID&columns%5B48%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B48%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B48%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B48%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B48%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B49%5D%5Bdata%5D=Asset_ID&columns%5B49%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B49%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B49%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B49%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B49%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B50%5D%5Bdata%5D=Service_ID&columns%5B50%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B50%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B50%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B50%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B50%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B51%5D%5Bdata%5D=Link_Service_ID&columns%5B51%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B51%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B51%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B51%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B51%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B52%5D%5Bdata%5D=Record_Date&columns%5B52%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B52%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B52%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B52%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B52%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B53%5D%5Bdata%5D=Record_Status&columns%5B53%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B53%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B53%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B53%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B53%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B54%5D%5Bdata%5D=RowNum&columns%5B54%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B54%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B54%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B54%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B54%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&arguments=get_presentation"
string(12) "Syntax error"
```

I don't know why is formatted like this, it looks having html entities, "%5B" should be "[". I don't know to convert and the php function are not working. I have used yet datatables before, and never noticed this. If I just do var_dump($_POST) I see the right structure, but why php://input doesn't work?

EDIT: just to develop i'm using windows 10, xampp php 8.0.2 and webpack without a main web server. I'm just browsing the page result of npm run build with Chrome.

EDIT2: I solved with parse_str in this way

```
if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
  parse_str($datajson,$data);
}
```

My question is kept, I would like solve without parse_str.

Comment: _“it looks having html entities, "%5B" should be "["”_ - that’s not HTML entities, that is URL encoding, which uses a percent sign followed by the two-digit hex byte value.

Comment: _“If I just do var_dump($_POST) I see the right structure, but why php://input doesn't work?”_ - it _did_ work, and gave you the raw post body content. This is the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding scheme used to encode normal form data sets for POST requests. If it was _not_ in this format, then PHP would not have automatically parsed it and populated $_POST with the individual values in the first place. The data you are sending here _is not_ JSON to begin with, yet you try to decode it as such.

Comment: In case it helps: You can see a list of the URL-decoded fields in the DataTables-generated request (for example, your `columns[0][data]` field) [in this page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters).

Comment: @andrewjames thank you i'm goingo to bookmark your resource

Comment: @CBroe this actually was my doubt, could it be really a json data? as you say it's not, and this explain more thing. I don't understand why this time I'm not sending json data from frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally solved with json data.
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26282/posting-json-with-built-in-ajax-functionality
Based on the link above I modified my js in this way:

```
$('#foo').DataTable({
 "processing": true,
 "serverSide": true,
 "ajax": {
    "url": uri_api,
    "method": "POST",
    "data": function(d) {
        return JSON.stringify($.extend(d, { "arguments" : "get_foo"}));
    }
 },
"columns": [
  { "data": "ONE" },
  { "data": "TWO" },
  { "data": "THREE" }
 ]
});
```

I didn't figure out that default data type were not json, in my previous implementation I used another js library instead of datatables, I used tabulator.
Since I got experience with datatables I choose this library for this new project which will be develop with webpack, and in my previous datatables implementation I really was not using a backend like now with api and a proper instance but just standalone ad hoc scripts and the script I was using for the serverside pagination of datatables was written with $_POST input, not json as I thought. I forgot this detail. Whereas tabulator was using natively the json data. Well, thank you very much.
Regards.